# karma-coverage files not created while singleRun = true

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha, karma-coverage

I am using Karma to run my unit tests and am now trying to incorporate `karma-coverage` into my process.
I am using `PhantomJS` to run the tests with `singleRun: true`. Whenever I do this, my code coverage reporter does not seem to be running. If I set `singleRun: false`, the folder and files are created.

Why is the karma coverage tool not running?

Here is my config file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs', 'sinon-chai'],
    files: [
     { pattern: 'bower_components/angular/angular.js', included: false },
     { pattern: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js', included: false },
     { pattern: 'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', included: false },
     { pattern: '**/*.js', included: false },
     { pattern: 'KarmaTests/test-main.js', included: true },
     { pattern: 'KarmaTests/**/*Test*.js', included: false }
    ],

    preprocessors: {
        'KarmaTests/*/*.js': ['coverage']
    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    coverageReporter: {
        type: 'html',
        dir: '_testCoverage/',
        file: 'cover.html'
    },

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,

        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

        //files are created when false, are not when true
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

Comment: What version of `karma` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor is intended to map the source files, not the test files. Do the following:

- Change the preprocessor pattern to:

  ```
      preprocessors: {
        '/**/*.js': ['coverage']
      },
  ```
- And add the JS files to the test mapping:

  ```
      { pattern: '**/*.js', included: true }
  ```
- Rerun karma and view the results